# Google chome command line switch not working on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, chromium

I'm trying to pass the following command line switches to Google chrome (Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit)) on OSX 10.9 and it's not working:

**/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --proxy-server="99.99.99.99:66" --remote-debugging-port=9999 google.com**

Not going through the proxy and remote debugging port is not opened. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you **close all instances of Chrome first** before running the command. It also looks like, at least from my tests, that it only supports HTTP proxies. The SOCKS proxy I created via an SSH tunnel didn't seem to work for me, whereas after I configured `tinyproxy`, it worked fine.

Comment: SOCKS proxy requires the proxy parameter to be in this format: --proxy-server="socks://99.99.99.99:66"

Comment: @John Cool! Did you get yours to work in the end?